# Android Fragment is not added

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I am trying to add a fragment to an activity, and the app keep refuses to inflate or add the fragment layout. The app is not crashing or anything, just a blank white screen that belongs to the activity

Here is the Activity code:

```
public class MovieDetail extends ActionBarActivity {
  String Tag = "TAG";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);

    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, Tag).commit();

    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  }
```

and here is the fragment class

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


public BlankFragment() {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    return root;
 }
```

for the layouts

The Activity xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/weather_detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ahmad.popularmovies01.Activities.MovieDetail"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

and the fragment Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

... etc
```

Comment: could you try to use add(R.id.weather_detail_container, fragment,tag);

Comment: Right. The fragment is not added to a container, thats all...

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
          add(0,fragment, Tag).commit();
```

same as

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
          add( fragment,Tag).commit();
```

Here your Id is 0, so its just added to the Activity but not binded with any view.